# Embedded SVN Revision # in an Exported C-File

Tags: svn

I have a C/C++ project built on several different Linux/Unix/AIX hosts, so being able to reference a Build # is incredibly helpful.  I have the code already in to do the classic $Rev$ SVN Keyword thing and print it out when I need it, however that number only updates whenever I modify the 1 file containing it (which happens to be one of the most infrequently edited files in the entire repository).

I typically 'svn export' my repos and create a tarball before moving it to another host, so svnversion won't work (just returns 'exported', on the few machines that even have SVN installed).  I'm wondering if there's a better way to get this number rather than building an 'svn export' script that will somehow run svnversion and embed it in my source.

I use CMake for my build system.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get "this" number where **exactly**?
2. Which "this" rev-no? Last commit in WC tree, head revision of WC-repo
3. Which OS do you have?

> I typically 'svn export' my repos and create a tarball before moving it to another host, so svnversion

Must be called inside WC before export, obviously

And if you have code in tarball, maybe you want to have revision **in filename**, not in files inside archive, if global resision-id is needed for information?

As Windows-based TSVN-user, I use [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) in my build-scripts in order to get and store some repository-info

- Post-commit client hook perform `SubWCRev.exe <path> Builder.tpl  Builder.bat ... call Builder.bat`, where Builder-template contain `svn export ... z:\trunk$WCDATE=%Y%m%d$-r$WCREV$`, and every macro in template expanded into real data in subwcrev-processed file
- My include-template, which have WCDATE construct too, also pre-processed with subwcrev

For Linux, port of SubWCRev exist with the same functionality: [SVNWCRev](http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/) (not tested) and nice [SvnRev](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm) (which is *actively developed* contrary to SVNWCRev) with some extending to SubWCRev|SVNWCRev

Comment: I'm doing development on a LInux (RHEL5) box, but deployment is done (by me) on a collection of SUSE, RHEL5, RHEL6, Debian, AIX, Solaris, etc boxes.  And I would like the repository version in code so that I can embed it in Debug logs & such so that users can see it when they report bugs.

Comment: `svnversion` in WC, some `svnlook` subcommands if repository is on local filesystem, `svn info` + grep inside WC or exported dir